# Displaying a message only once; cannot make it go away

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hei folks!
I keep wrestling with this thing on the RPS project for quite some time now, where I display a message when it's tie, but I can't figure a solution to make it go away when the round it's not a tie.

The game plays good, except for the last two else if's. on one, I tried to show the message when the player's choice is identical with the cpu's, and show the message, and on the other message, I thought that I could make an if to replace the previous tie message with an empty string, by using an if like if playerselection !== computerplay then the string from tie message, would change to this ' '. but obviously not working!
I will leave here the code

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="queries.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
      <h2>Play a round of 5 games of Rock, Paper, Scissors!</h2>
      <h3>Good luck!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button
        class="rockBtn"
        value="ROCK"
        onclick="playerSelection(this.value)"
      >
        <img class="img-button" src="img/rock-min.png" alt="rock button" />
      </button>
      <button
        class="paperBtn"
        value="PAPER"
        onclick="playerSelection(this.value)"
      >
        <img class="img-button" src="img/paper-min.png" alt="paper button" />
      </button>
      <button
        class="scissorsBtn"
        value="SCISSORS"
        onclick="playerSelection(this.value)"
      >
        <img class="img-button" src="img/scissors-min.png" alt="" />
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="score-tracker">
      <div>Player Score - <span id="playerscore">0</span></div>
      <div>Computer Score - <span id="computerscore">0</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="selectedChoices">
      <div class="playerSelected">
        You have picked - <span id="playerpick"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="cpuSelected">
        CPU has picked - <span id="cpupick"><em></em></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="game-decisions">
      <div class="playerWinn">
        <span id="playerWin"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="cpuWinn"><span id="cpuWin"></span></div>
      <div></div>
      <div class="tieRound"><span id="tieGame"></span></div>
    </div>
    <button class="reset">Reset the score!</button>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</html>
```

```
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 900px;
}

html {
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(127, 69, 69), rgb(200, 168, 168));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

h2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: darkred;
}

h3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.active {
  background-color: white;
  color: blue;
}

#rockBtn:hover,
#paperBtn:hover,
#scissorsBtn:hover {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: #e9f01d;
  cursor: crosshair;
  box-shadow: 2px 8px rgb(181, 180, 180);
}

#paperBtn,
#scissorsBtn,
#rockBtn {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 0.7rem;
  color: white;
}

#start {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.score-tracker {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(122, 165, 42);
}

#playerscore,
#computerscore {
  color: #000;
}

.selectedChoices {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.game-decisions {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(80, 53, 53);
  font-weight: bold;
  /* display: flex;
  justify-content: center; */
  /* flex-direction: column; */
}

#playerWin {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: rgb(30, 115, 213);
  font-size: 22px;
}

#cpuWin {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: rgb(30, 115, 213);
  font-size: 22px;
}

#playerpick,
#cpupick {
  color: rgb(23, 132, 132);
}

.reset {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(71, 186, 228);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 20rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.reset:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 35px rgb(102, 182, 48);
}

button {
  border: none;
  background-color: rgb(99, 95, 136);
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3rem;
}

.active,
button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 99, 47);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 35px rgb(226, 240, 28);
  color: yellow;
  transition-delay: 2ms;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.img-button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```
  let choices = ["ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS"];
  let randomPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
  console.log(choices[randomPick]);
  return choices[randomPick];
}
let overallWinner;
let computerScore = 0;
let playerScore = 0;

function playerSelection(val) {
  return val;
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerPlay) {
  if (playerSelection == "ROCK" && computerPlay == "SCISSORS") {
    playerScore++;
    playerScoreHtml.textContent = playerScore;
    playerPickHtml.textContent = playerSelection;
    cpuPickHtml.textContent = computerPlay;
  } else if (playerSelection == "PAPER" && computerPlay == "ROCK") {
    playerScore++;
    playerScoreHtml.textContent = playerScore;
    playerPickHtml.textContent = playerSelection;
    cpuPickHtml.textContent = computerPlay;
  } else if (playerSelection == "SCISSORS" && computerPlay == "PAPER") {
    playerScore++;
    playerScoreHtml.textContent = playerScore;
    playerPickHtml.textContent = playerSelection;
    cpuPickHtml.textContent = computerPlay;
  } else if (playerSelection == "ROCK" && computerPlay == "PAPER") {
    computerScore++;
    computerScoreHtml.textContent = computerScore;
    playerPickHtml.textContent = playerSelection;
    cpuPickHtml.textContent = computerPlay;
  } else if (playerSelection == "PAPER" && computerPlay == "SCISSORS") {
    computerScore++;
    computerScoreHtml.textContent = computerScore;
    playerPickHtml.textContent = playerSelection;
    cpuPickHtml.textContent = computerPlay;
  } else if (playerSelection == "SCISSORS" && computerPlay == "ROCK") {
    computerScore++;
    computerScoreHtml.textContent = computerScore;
    playerPickHtml.textContent = playerSelection;
    cpuPickHtml.textContent = computerPlay;
  } else if (playerSelection === computerPlay) {
    let tieMessage = "It's a tie!";
    console.log(tieMessage);
    tieHtml.textContent = tieMessage;
    playerPickHtml.textContent = playerSelection;
    cpuPickHtml.textContent = playerSelection;
  } else if (playerSelection !== computerPlay) {
    tieHtml.textContent = "";
  }
}

function game(e) {
  const selectedValue = e.currentTarget.value;
  console.log(e.currentTarget, "button value");
  playRound(playerSelection(selectedValue), computerPlay());
  if (computerScore == 5) {
    const cpuWinner = "The CPU has won. Pretty shameful, don't  you think?";
    console.log(cpuWinner);
    cpuWin.textContent = cpuWinner;
  } else if (playerScore == 5) {
    const playerWinner = "You have won!";
    console.log(playerWinner);
    playerWin.textContent = playerWinner;
  }
  // Disable buttons, dictating the game is over whenever a player reaches the score of 5.
  if (computerScore == 5 || playerScore == 5) {
    rockBtn.disabled = true;
    paperBtn.disabled = true;
    scissorsBtn.disabled = true;
  }
}

const rockBtn = document.querySelector(".rockBtn");
rockBtn.addEventListener("click", game);

const paperBtn = document.querySelector(".paperBtn");
paperBtn.addEventListener("click", game);

const scissorsBtn = document.querySelector(".scissorsBtn");
scissorsBtn.addEventListener("click", game);

const playerScoreHtml = document.querySelector("#playerscore");
const computerScoreHtml = document.querySelector("#computerscore");
console.log(computerScoreHtml);
console.log(playerScoreHtml);

const playerPickHtml = document.querySelector("#playerpick");
const cpuPickHtml = document.querySelector("#cpupick");

const playerWin = document.querySelector("#playerWin");
const tieHtml = document.querySelector("#tieGame");

//refresh page for new game
const resetBtn = document.querySelector(".reset");
resetBtn.addEventListener("click", () => location.reload());

let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    buttons.forEach((btn) => btn.classList.remove("active"));
    this.classList.add("active");
  });
});
```

Figured it out somehow, but I'm afraid I've written too much code already.
So when it's a tie, it will be like
`tieHtml.textcontent = 'It's a tie'`
and to make it go away, I've used at any other if a
`tieHtml.textcontent = ''` so an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `else` in front of the last `if`.

Because when the selections aren't the same, it will trigger any of the above `if`s and therefore not trigger the `else`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the div where you display the result like so:

```
<div class="game-decisions">
      <div class="decision">
        <span id="game-result"></span>
      </div>
</div>
```

and update the innerText of game-result in your javascript according to the game state in your conditional statements to "player wins", "computer wins" "it's a tie" it will make your javascript a few lines shorter your html too.
if their displayed differently (like in a different position...etc) you can do that by adding class names via your javascript and styling them in your css.

Comment: if you don't want to reformat your code, removing the else as in @LordSami 's answer will work for resetting the tie message,